# How often does android requests location updates?

Tags: android, geolocation, coordinates, locationmanager, proximity

How often does android requests location updates? For example if you add a proximity alert to a location manager how often will it update the location?

In the documentation it says: "In case the screen goes to sleep, checks for proximity alerts happen only once every 4 minutes. This conserves battery life by ensuring that the device isn't perpetually awake"

But what if the screen doesn't go to sleep?

Thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `LocationManager` class, there is a method called `requestLocationUpdates` that can be called with different set of parameters. It "Registers the current activity to be notified periodically based on the specified criteria."
Two of the parameters are:

minTime: the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.
minDistance: the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters

see the documentation for `[LocationManager][1]`

And whenever you use it, don't forget to remove the updates whenever you don't need it anymor i.e. in `onPause()`

I hope that helps

Comment: So if you don't call the requestLocationUpdates method  dont you get location updates just by instantiating the locationManager?

Comment: @mixkat Thats tight, you need to call the requestLocationUpdates for a constant update, you can also use getLastKnownLocation(String provider) if you are interested in just one location, however it probably won't be very accurate.